# With certain wifi router and laptop, if I connect I get 5 pings that is it

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I have a windows 10 laptop: lenovo yoga that when I try to connect to a certain wifi router, if I ping while I connect, I get 5 or so good fast pings, and then they all timeout.  Everything else can connect to this router.  I tried connecting to 5Ghz or 2.4Ghz channel, and the same thing.  I can't figure out why it would work for a second but then not work. I have tried disabiling firewall/defender but to no avail. Any ideas?

This is a newer Lenova Yoga with up to date windows 10 and drivers.

Comment: Is ping the only thing affected, or are there other consequences? Please don't make us guess.

Answer (score 1):

#### Any ideas?

Try completely reinitialising all network states.

Run the following commands in an elevated `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`

Comment: It didn't work, but ended up just getting a new router.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a third party anti-virus product installed?  If so, has it been updated to the latest version available?  I've seen several Windows 10 systems suddenly loose most network connectivity after a recent Windows Update. Fixed by uninstalling the old anti-virus product. Still worked after installing the latest version of same anti-virus product.